# Can I remotely delete social tag of a different user?

Tags: 2010, web-services, social

I have a user control that runs outside of SharePoint, and uses a combination of web services and the client object model to retrieve information about pages tagged by users.

My next step is to allow the user to remove a tag on a specific page. I have a feature-equivalent web part in SharePoint that does the job well enough, but the COM doesn't expose any of the social features, and the web service only allows for deleting tags of the user whose credentials are being used in the web service.

So my question is:

- Is there a way within the web service model to delete a tag of another user, that isn't documenteD?
- If not, is there a way for me to "spoof" as another user within the web services?

It is sadly not possible for me to retrieve the users login details from them, as it's part of a larger website and all authentication is handled outside of the system.